# alternative to data.frame for multi-dimensional arrays

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, tidyverse

Recently I have been manipulating (grouping, summarizing, and plotting) ~10GB size (~50 million rows) tabular data using data.frames (with `tidyr/dplyr/ggplot2`).  The performance is a bit slow and I am looking for ways to speed it up. One obvious choice is `data.table`, which I am starting to learn.

The other glaring possibility is the data structure. These data are ordered (no missing cases) and can probably be represented by multi-dimensional arrays in stead of data.frame.  Below is a trivial example

```
tibble::tribble(
  ~g1, ~g2,      ~g3, ~value1, ~valeu2,
    1, "a",    "low",      10,      12,
    1, "a", "middle",      20,      13,
    1, "a",   "high",      11,      15,
    1, "b",    "low",       9,       4,
    1, "b", "middle",       4,       3,
    1, "b",   "high",       5,       2
  )
```

Of course the real data has many more grouping variables. They take most of the spaces but do contains little information.

Not knowing anything about the inner working of R and the packages,  I am thinking that we can just look up the values from the indexed position in the array directly, whereas data.frame requires us to filter through all grouping variables first (although indexing may help).  And grouped operation can be similarly direct and fast.

So my questions is, what's the best way to represent and handle these type of data?  `data.frame` is convenient with all the packages, but do we have a container for the arrays with good efficiencies?  Or do we have packages that can take advantage of the fully structured & sorted data?

Comment: Maybe this https://gitlab.com/jangorecki/data.cube if vanilla data.table doesn't suffice (I have not tried it)

Comment: thanks for the "data cube" link.  I take a quick look.  It is based on `data.table`.  Guess I need to dive into `data.table` first

Comment: Btw, it looks like some features of cube might be in data.table now. They're in Jan's presentation from earlier this month: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Presentations (click the image to open his slides).